# Series of movies with robots in sync with electronic music

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots, animation

In 4th or 5th grade in America in 2014 or 2015, the teacher showed us a video from a DVD of robots moving (sort of dancing, too) in sync with instrumental electronic music. It was probably from the mid-2000s to 2015, and was part of a series. I think the logo had some sort of 3D thing with it, and the name probably contained "robots."

It was 3D animated, with lots of special effects like sparks and fire. There were tons of kinds of robots in different sizes and shapes. The robots were all on some sort of big flat square platform.

Comment: That strangely reminds me of this video.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rn8Uy4H10zw

Comment: @DeeV seems worthy of an answer

Comment: My immediate thought was Bots Master, and the intro does have some dancing robots. It did have some moments that were 3d-animated (you could wear glasses to see it in 3D), but most of it is flat 2D animation.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLKYOSiW7U4&t=18s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The description closely resembles "[Starship Groove](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rn8Uy4H10zw)" music video as part of the [Animusic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animusic) series.

Animusic was a series of video DVDs from the early 2000s to early 2010s. They featured 3D animated music videos. Often times of elaborate music machines that plays the song. It was popular to play them school (at least according to the YouTube comments. My school didn't play them). "[Pipe Dream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyCIpKAIFyo)" was also used as a demo for the Intel Radeon 9700 graphics card and featured in SIGGRAPH in 2001.  "Starship Groove" was a demo video for Apple's QuickTime.

The Starship Groove music video features robots on stage performing the music and dancing.

Comment: Yup, that’s it! Starship Groove looks a whole ton like the thing I saw, with the robots coming out of the ground.